# Get path of uploaded file inside a Twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I've created a teaser template like this `node--type--teaser.html.twig`.
Within that template I want to conditionally create a link to a file that was uploaded via the field `field_pdf`.

How do you extract JUST the path to the pdf in the template.

I've tried `{{ file_url(node.field_pdf.entity.url.value) }}` but that just brings back an empty path.

If thats not possible, is there a way to get a file path from the `fid` in twig?

Comment: I think the field name is `uri`, not `url`.

Comment: Yo, thinking the same. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#file_url there it's `{{ file_url(node.field_example_image.entity.uri.value) }}`.

Comment: Per the answer below, make sure the field type is set as `File`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Manage teaser Display : Change Format of your file field to `Generic File` From  `admin/structure/types/manage/YouRContentType/display/teaser` .
2. In your twig `node--type--teaser.html.twig` just print  `{{ 
   file_url(node.field_pdf.entity.uri.value) }}` you will get the path to your file.
   **Note** : As mentioned in comment it's `uri` Not `url`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is this `generic file` setting? All i see is `Rendered Entity`, `Entity ID`, `Label` and `Thumbnail` as output options.

Comment: is your field of type `File ? ` if is the case From your Manage display page of your content type you will see a dropdown `Column FORMAT` some option `RSS enclosure, Generic file, URL to file, Table of files` .

Comment: Ah, thats probably what the issue is. I set the file type as `Media`. Updating this now.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. The issue was as stated where I'd selected the `Media` field type instead of the `File` field type. With the `File` field type, the `Generic File` format is available in the teaser view mode.

Comment: You are welcome, Can you just please add this as note to the question `Field of type File` just in case someone need it.   Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a paragraph type with a file field.
I wanted to get a url of file-field inside paragraph's template.
Not sure why but above solution of @berramou did not work for me.

So what I did is, in manage display I changed the file field's format to "URL to file".
Then I rendered the file field, stripped its tags, trimmed and passed it to file_url like follows:

```
{% set url = file_url(content.field_pdf_file|render|striptags|trim) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a field template file (for example, */themes/custom/y_subtheme/templates/field/field--node--field-brochure--course.html.twig*), it will be `{{ file_url(item.content['#file'].getFileUri()) }}`.